# How to move unallocated space from left to the right of an ext4 partition in gparted without extended partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

[image: partitions_picture]

Hello,

I just reduced my windows partition space on `/dev/nvme0n1p3` to the unallocated 60.65Go space on its right. I'm trying to allocate this space to my kde plasma partition on `/dev/nvmee0n1p4` in vain because I cant move this one to the left with gparted but only resize to the right. The only thing I can do is playing with the windows partition to resize it. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

I'm using gparted on the kde partition. I read about extended partition and command lines to do this but I dont have one here and I'm not really familiar with this so I'm not sure. I really don't want to mess up with this. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move the partition on which your currently booted OS is located. The filesystem on moved partition must be unmounted and you can't unmount root filesystem.

The solution is to boot from a flash drive with Linux on it. This way you won't have to have filesystem on that partition mounted.